# pre-load ionic component that can work in offline mode

Tags: ionic4

I am looking to pre-load ionic components. I have built a mobile app, but the challenge i have is that when i visit a page that uses the component e.g date-picker, it initially displays nothing and then only once the component is downloaded is it displayed. The lag is about 2-3 seconds.

What makes this really inconvenient is that my app works in offline mode with a SW, and if this page is visited when there is no connection is breaks completely.

Is there a way i can pre-bundle the component, i am using them in a standalone ionic app.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. The components should be able to work offline unless your transmitting data through an API during the process of your component.

Comment: The components only get loaded when you go to the route that has the component on it. (lazy loaded) if at that point the application is offline, it does not work.

Comment: You can try starting here. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-3-lazy-loading-of-pages-fails-if-no-internet-connection/98113

Comment: many similar questions - unanswered.